# Caffe - How to imbalance Cifar10 data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm doing a research on the impact of imbalanced data with caffe framework. Now I am trying to make a new cifar10 distribution by trying to remove some of the data from specified class. I read the document of cifar10. It said that the .bin file has a data structure like

```
1*8 bit label data |   3*1024 for RGB pixel
```

So I write down a script to filter out the data for those class. And make a new .bin file.

Now I run the script on caffe and try to make a LMDB dataset

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# This script converts the cifar data into leveldb format.

EXAMPLE=examples/cifar10
DATA=data/cifar10
DBTYPE=lmdb

echo "Creating $DBTYPE..."

rm -rf $EXAMPLE/cifar10_train_$DBTYPE $EXAMPLE/cifar10_test_$DBTYPE

./build/examples/cifar10/convert_cifar_data.bin $DATA $EXAMPLE $DBTYPE

echo "Computing image mean..."

./build/tools/compute_image_mean -backend=$DBTYPE \
  $EXAMPLE/cifar10_train_$DBTYPE $EXAMPLE/mean.binaryproto

echo "Done."
```

However After I filter out those data. It seems that the IMDB still has the same size and doesn't look any different than the one without filtered. Can somebody tell me what should I do to make the data imbalanced?

Comment: what is the script you wrote? you do not provide enough information to understand your problem.

Comment: I open the .bin file and for each 3073 byte if(first_byte == 'class1') than delete this 3073 bytes.

Comment: My idea is to modify the original data before I run the ./examples/cifar10/create_cifar10.sh Because on the official document it doesn't point out how to actually make a dataset instead of mnist or cifar10

Comment: after changing all batches files in `data/cifar10` where do you save the changed bin files? do you rename them? can you verify that the changed bin files are indeed taking less disk space?

Comment: i dont rename them. they are still named `data_batch_1, data_batch_2 ...` And yes the file size does get smaller. I even remove all the data in data_batch_1(0 byte) But after I run  `./examples/cifar10/create_cifar10.sh` it still get the same result. The data size of cifar10_train_lmdb still the same.

Comment: have you corrected [`const int kCIFARBatchSize = 10000;`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cifar10/convert_cifar_data.cpp#L28)?

Comment: Yes I tried changed this varialbe and also I tried making the `const int kCIFARTrainBatches = 4;` in convert_cifar_data.cpp but result still get 206mb for cifar10_train_lmdb. Thanks so much for helping. I'm just wondering is my idea right to directly change the .bin file?

Comment: @Shai Can you tell me anything else that I can possibly miss?